# How to remove loaded Windows users using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, scripting, user-profile

I'm trying to remove Windows user profiles from the computer using PowerShell.

I'm already able to remove the users using the script bellow:

```
$users = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName $pc | where {(!$_.special)}

foreach ($user in $users) {
    if ($user.Loaded) {
        Write-Host "`nuser profile is loaded, please restart the computador and run the script again to remove it" -ForegroundColor Red
    } else {
        $user | Remove-WmiObject
    }
}
```

NOTE: I simplified the script for this question, but there are other checks that I do before removing the user.

I can't remove the loaded profiles this way. I am able to query the logged users using `quser` for example, and then I can use `rwinsta` to logoff a disconnected or active user, then I can remove these as well.

The problem is that not all users that has the loaded profile "true" are shown in the `quser` list. Is it possible for me to "unload" these user profiles without restarting the computer?

**There are some cases when the user is not logged on the computer but his profile still returns with the loaded as "true"**

Comment: Profiles of logged-in users can't be deleted, because Windows keeps some of the files in them open (the user's registry hive for instance). Why would you even want to delete a profile when the user is still logged in? What are you trying to achieve in the end?

Comment: Actually I don't want to remove the user profile when he is still logged on, the scenario is like this: We have 3 shifts on our company, and at least 3 users will log on using the same computer, there is cases when the user from another computer log in as well, so after some time, there is a lot of users on the machine... sometimes users leave their profile logged in on the computer and just change the user account, and so on.... And as I mentioned above, the users that are logged I can do a logoff using the quser and rwista.

Comment: Are these domain computers? If so, use group policies to restrict logon times, force logoff after hours, and clean up local copies of roaming profiles.

Comment: Thank you very much @AnsgarWiechers Wiechers for the solution. It is one way that we could do that. I will talk with the team and propose that. But for curiosity purpose, is it possible to unload the profile?

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstanding about how profiles work, but this is not the right place for a proper explanation. In a nutshell, profiles aren't loaded/unloaded. Files in the profile directory are opened at logon and closed at logoff by the OS, and trying to forcibly close them might cause some serious damage. So, essentially the only way to "unload" a user profile is to logoff the user.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for the explanation